# MailChimp: Disable Tracking for Opens and Clicks

Tags: emails

Is there a possibility to disable the tracking for opens and clicks? I know that this can be changed within mailchimp but can I disable this option with the Drupal mailchimp module somehow?

Comment: Any reason you won't do it within mailchimp?

Comment: Right now the user can create and send the campaign with Drupal, without logging into mailchimp at all.

Comment: If you want users to be able to decide on creation, describe that directly in your question, including outline of your user-created campaigns setup. Otherwise you may get answer that does not fit your use case at all.